# How to enumerate vertices in Geometry in JTS?

Tags: java, jts

Java Topology Suite has `Geometry` class, which has [`getNumPoints()`](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.html#getNumPoints%28%29) method. According to documentation, it counts all vertices in all constituent geometries.

How to enumerate all these points? They can be obtained by `getCoordinates()` method, but this looks not optimal, since (1) is not iterative and (2) requires to convert each coordinate tuple into `Point` by `GeomertFactory`.

Comment: Do you mean GeometryFactory instead of GeomertFactory, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably have some proper geometry type like LineString or Polygon, use that (cast your Geometry to it), then you can use `getPointN(index)`.

Coordinates are not Points by the way. Coordinate is not a geometry in JTS, just a class to hold numeric values. Points are actual geometries.